# View Android webview network requests that occurred on page load in Chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

If you have a webview open in Android, you can inspect it in Chrome devtools. However, I can't open the devtools first, then open the webview to log network requests that occur on page load. Is there a way to log network requests that occur as soon as the webview loads?

Also, refreshing the page behaves differently from the initial load because the page modifies the URL.

Comment: What if you lock/unlock device?

Comment: @MBDevelop how would that work? I still need to open the webview before locking the device

Comment: Why not just change the location back to the original URL using window.location?

Comment: @Kyle stuff run onload

Comment: @LeoJiang Do you mean window.onload?

Comment: Actually, I think you're right, that could work. It's not ideal, but I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept various components of WebView communication by implementing your own `WebViewClient`. A short snippet is below:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView,
        request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
        // Use the `request` object as needed.
    } 
}
```

More information regarding the `WebViewClient`, including other possible overrides, can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient).